# How to extract the node from the subsequent page after clicking the submit button using selenium and xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use `xpath` to test a site.  I have been able to go to the site, enter a value in the input text box and submit. But for my next portion, I need to go to the URL that the site goes to after submitting the input button. This is what I have so far:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='keyword']").send_keys(company_name)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button').click()
```

After the click, the page navigates to a different url than the one I initially provided. The next page is where all the remaining test needs to be performed. I could find out any information on how to retrieve the url for the next page and rerun the driver to locate other nodes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the driver is already there, just issue new commands... no need for the url or to rerun the driver.  The driver is automating the browser... but the browser is also responding to the web site as it normally would.

Comment: I don't understand problem - after clicking button it loads new page and you can work with new HTML on this page - you don't need to use `get(url)` for this.

Comment: @pcalkins, but when I used the save driver to collect the node, it always comes out empty. I used the same command on the console using `$x("//div[@class='test']/a")[0].text`, it shows me the value

Comment: @furas, okay I understand. I only assumed I have to rerun the url because when I tried to retrieve the nodes, it always comes out empty

Comment: maybe you have to wait for awhile so browser has time to load all data or run JavaScript which loads data.

Comment: @furas, good point. I'm checking it now

Comment: BTW: see Selenium [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) functions. But I often use `time.sleep(2)` because it is easier to remeber it.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using Waits function? I also use time.sleep

Comment: as I know `time.sleep(10)` waits exactly 10 seconds but `Wait` with condition checks condition every 0.5s and stop waiting when condition gives True - so it can wait shorter.

Comment: @furas, Awesome!! Thank you for your help. I did forget to wait so that's why I was getting empty array. It's working now. Thank you so much!!